# Exponential in the category Relation

Tags: category-theory

Is it possible to define exponential and currying in the category Relation? If not, what is the reason that we cannot?

Answer (score 5):

The category $\mathbf{Rel}$ has a zero object, i.e. an object that is both initial and terminal. On the other hand, any cartesian closed category with a zero object must be trivial: indeed,
$$X \cong 1 \times X \cong 0 \times X \cong 0$$
since $(-) \times X$ preserves colimits. But $\mathbf{Rel}$ is not a trivial category, so it is not cartesian closed.

Mind you, the product in $\mathbf{Rel}$ is not the cartesian product – it is the disjoint union. If you allow yourself the cartesian product in $\mathbf{Rel}$, you get a symmetric monoidal closed category – but since
$$\mathbf{Rel} (X \otimes Y, Z) \cong \mathbf{Rel} (X, Y \otimes Z)$$
we still do not get the usual set of functions.